# Test code for trigger that prevents deletion of contentdocument by specific user

Tags: apex, unit-test

I built a trigger that is meant to prevent deletion of files by a specific user (our integration user) of files created by other users. I have written test code as well, but the code is covering 0% of my trigger, and I am not sure why not. Can you please provide insight, and show what I need to fix in my test? Here is the trigger and test that I am working with.

TRIGGER:

```
trigger FileDeletionPrevention on ContentDocument (before delete) {
    if (trigger.isBefore){
    for (ContentDocument cd : trigger.old){
            Id deleter = UserInfo.getUserId();
            Id uploader = cd.CreatedById;
        if (deleter == '0051N000006BSeyQAG'){
            if (deleter != uploader){
                cd.adderror('File cannot be deleted');
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

TEST:

```
@isTest(seealldata = true)
public class FileDeletionPreventionTest {

   @isTest
    public static void fileDeleter(){

        
        user u = [select id, name from user where id='0051N000006BSeyQAG'];
        
        Test.startTest();
        
      ContentVersion cv=new Contentversion();
        cv.title='ABC';
        cv.PathOnClient ='test';
        Blob b=Blob.valueOf('Unit Test Attachment Body');
        cv.versiondata=EncodingUtil.base64Decode('Unit Test Attachment Body');
        insert cv;
        
        System.runas(u){
            id cvDocId = cv.ContentDocumentId;
          list<contentDocument> cd = [select id from contentdocument where id =:cvDocId];
            delete cd;
        }
        Test.stopTest();
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proximate issue is that this query doesn't return anything:

```
      list<contentDocument> cd = [select id from contentdocument where id =:cvDocId];
```

because `cv.ContentDocumentId` is not automatically populated on insert, and is `null` here. You must query for this value before you can use it.

Your unit test will actually fail if you succeed in getting it to do what you want, because that `delete cd` DML operation is going to throw a `DmlException`. You'll want to use a pattern that traps that exception and asserts that the *right* exception was thrown due to your trigger action, e.g.,

```
Boolean thrown = false;
try {
    delete cd;
} catch (DmlException d) {
    System.assert(d.getMessage().contains('File cannot be deleted'), 'correct exception message');
    thrown = true;
}
System.assert(thrown, 'exception should be thrown');
```

I would also strongly encourage you to use a Custom Setting to store the Id of the user to whom this should apply. Hard-coding Ids is a bad practice that creates fragility and maintenance requirements in your code. You should also never use the `@seeAllData=true` annotation unless you know for sure that you are in one of the very few situations that requires it.

Comment: Excellent- this worked! Thanks a lot